# How can I use Neo4j with Lucene 4

Tags: java, neo4j, titan

I have an application that currently works with Titan graph database which uses Lucene 4.4. for the indexing. In the same application I want to work also with the Neo4j graph database, which unfortunately uses Lucene 3.6. For this reason I get compile errors. Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: If you are using Maven, you can put one of the Lucene dependencies in its own project and use [Maven Shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) to rename the Lucene references in the bytecode of the project depending on Neo4j. In my case this required moving the Neo4j dependencies into a separate project, but works great (in particular the [class relocation feature](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html)).

---

ORIGINAL POST:
It seems like Neo4j doesn't support Lucene 4 and doesn't intend to. Here's a couple informative links:

[Alternative IndexProvider for Neo4J 1.9.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17469946/alternative-indexprovider-for-neo4j-1-9-1)

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/6

Here's the github repo where someone wrote an index provider for Neo4j to be compatible with Lucene 4. I've no idea how well it works, as I am not yet desperate enough to try it (yet), but it appears to be the only thing out there.